# Cannot upload from Drive via YouTube Data API in Google Apps Script: empty response

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-data-api

I am trying to import a list of files from Google Drive to YouTube. The meta-data and the URL to the file are in a Google spreadsheet, so I wrote some code using Google Apps Script that does the following

1. Get the selected rows
2. Retrieve title, description, Google Drive URL
3. Load the file from Google Drive via [`DriveApp.getFileById`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFileById(String))
4. Upload the blob to YouTube using the title and description via [`YouTube.Videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)
5. Update the selected row with the YouTube video id from the response

The upload looks something like this

```
var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
var resource = {
    snippet: {
        title: 'The title',
        description: 'A long description ...',
        defaultLanguage: 'de',
        categoryId: 17,
        tags: [ 'Sport', 'Fitness' ],
    },
    status: {
        privacyStatus: 'unlisted'
    }
}
try {
    var result = YouTube.Videos.insert(resource, "snippet,status", blob);
    return result.id;
} catch (err) {
    console.log({message: 'Error ' + err.message, error: err});
}
```

This code has already worked about a year ago. I have adapted it slightly, but now I do not get a response from the `YouTube.Videos.insert` call. The following is logged inside the catch:

> message: Error Empty response
>
> error: Exception: Empty response

Not very helpful.

Before uploading, I do a [`YouTube.Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)
to get a target channel in case there are multiple channels available. For this request, I have to permit access to my data and I am only asked on the first invocation. I also see the script in the list of [applications for my Google account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions). I assume permissions are ok.

Any suggestions on how I can get more information on the issue, or is there something I should do differently?

---

Regarding the target channel (and this might be a different question), I cannot really use this, as it seems I can only upload to a specific channel, if I am a YouTube content partner (see parameters [onBehalfOfContentOwner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#onBehalfOfContentOwner) and [onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel)):

> **Note**: This parameter is intended exclusively for YouTube content partners.

Comment: I have raised an issue on the Apps Script issue tracker: [#68799876 Cannot upload Blob from Drive to YouTube](https://issuetracker.google.com/68799876)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem in my project and here's what I have figured out: if your video file size is more than **10 Mb**, you will get `Empty response` error.

Probably (can't say officialy because no documentation mentions it) this is happening because Google Apps Script's `YouTube.Videos.insert` (and all other available built-in services) uses `UrlFetchApp` under the hood, which have restriction of 10 Mb per call: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations. You can check it yourself using your sample code: if file is under 10 Mb, it will be uploaded successfully.

As possible workaround, you can use idea from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44853845/555121

Basically, you will need to open modal window using `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog` and then perform upload to YouTube via plain JavaScript inside modal dialog, which have no restrictions on transferred data size. Here's good example of YouTube resumable upload implementation: https://github.com/sangnvus/2015SUMJS01/blob/master/WIP/Sources/FlyAwayPlus/FlyAwayPlus/Scripts/youtube-upload.js

Comment: Great answer! I did not test the solution you provided, but I think this is the reason. The reason to run inside of Apps Script is that I wanted to avoid doing networking on the client side, so I will put everything in a script to run outside of the client.